# how can i add multi GPU to huggingface models?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

```
test_dataset = load_dataset("scientific_papers", DATASET_NAME, split="test", cache_dir=CACHE_DIR)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_ID)
model = BigBirdPegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(MODEL_ID).to(DEVICE)    

def generate_answer(batch):
  inputs_dict = tokenizer(batch["article_text"], padding="max_length", max_length=4096, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True)
  inputs_dict = {k: inputs_dict[k].to(DEVICE) for k in inputs_dict}
  predicted_abstract_ids = model.generate(**inputs_dict, max_length=256, num_beams=5, length_penalty=0.8)
  batch["predicted_abstract"] = tokenizer.decode(predicted_abstract_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
  print(batch["predicted_abstract"])
  return batch

result = test.map(generate_answer)
```

I'd like to add muli GPU code to my code is it possible to do it with just one line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apex](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex). Not sure if its compatible with this exact model, but I have been using it with Roberta, you should be able to insert this after line 3:

```
from apex.parallel import DistributedDataParallel as DDP
model = DDP(model)
```